# True or false? There is a linear mapping $\psi: \mathbb{R}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]$ with $\psi(x)=x^2$ and $\psi(x^2)=x$, whereby..

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> True or false? There is a linear mapping $\psi: \mathbb{R}[x]
> \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]$ with $\psi(x)=x^2$ and $\psi(x^2)=x$,
>   whereby $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is the vector space of the real polynomials.

It's another task I found on the internet but sadly there was no solution. Can you please tell me how tasks like that are solved correctly, it might be asked in our exam even though it's not on our script, at least I couldn't find it.

But I don't see how there could be a linear mapping when we have $\psi(x)$
and $\psi(x^2)$, so I would say it's false but I have no idea actually :(

Answer (score 3):

This maps polynomials onto polynomials, and swaps the terms of first and second degree.

For example:

$$\psi(3x^2-5x)=-5x^2+3x$$

Did this help?

Answer (score 3):

The idea here is that the set $\{1,x,x^2,\dots,x^n,\dots\}$ is a basis for the set of all polynomials.

Take your favorite polynomial $p(x)$, and write it down as:
$$p(x) = 1 + 2x +15x^2 + x^4$$
(or whatever the polynomial ends up being).
We can view this as a linear combination of basis "vectors":
$$p(x) = e_0 + 2e_1 + 15e_2 + e_4$$
where $e_i = x^i$.

In terms of this basis, you want a linear transformation $T$ such that $T(e_1) = e_2$ and $T(e_2) = e_1$, but $T(e_i) = e_i$ for all other $i$.
We can't exactly write down a matrix for this (because the transformation is between two infinite-dimensional vector spaces), but if we could it'd look like:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &\dots & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &\dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & & \ddots & & \dots & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
This is because this is the "matrix" that only permutes two basis vectors.